# Center group of buttons in browser

Tags: html, css

I know this is simple, yet I can't figure it out because I don't know CSS. I tried a few google options but it won't work. What I want to do is put a pair of buttons in the center of the browser (vertically and horizontally). I tried putting the pair of buttons in a `div` tag but anytime i did that, the buttons disappeared. My idea was to put the buttons in a `div` tag and center that div on the screen. Any ideas how to work this out. Got a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/um7ctpnj/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('#show').click(function(){
  $( "div:hidden:first" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
 });
 $('#hide').click(function(){
  $( "div" ).fadeOut("fast");
 });
});
```

```css
  div {
    margin: 3px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
  }
  #one {
    background: #f00;
  }
  #two {
    background: #0f0;
  }
  #three {
    background: #00f;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>


    <title>Button Show</title>

  <body>
   
<body>
   
    <button id="show" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button> 
    <button id="hide" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hide Me Now!</button> 

    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say center the div, do you mean horizontally and vertically?

Comment: yes. vertically and horizontally @Lee

Comment: When you wrap the buttons in a DIV they disappear because your CSS says so `div { display: none; }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your buttons disappear when you wrap them in a DIV is because your CSS says not to display DIVs by default.

```css
.numbered > div {
    margin: 3px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
}
.btn-holder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    translate: transform( -50%, -50% );
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-holder">
    <button id="show" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button> 
    <button id="hide" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hide Me Now!</button>
</div>

<div class="numbered">
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>
</div>
```

I wrapped your DIVs that had `display: none;` applied to them in another DIV with a class of `.numbered` and updated the CSS selector so that every single DIV is not `display: none;` and all the other properties you applied to DIVs. Might be helpful if you need more DIVs added to the page.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of wrapping the buttons in a div, use another element (like a `<section>`)

Then:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show').click(function() {
    $("div:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
  });
  $('#hide').click(function() {
    $("div").fadeOut("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
  div {
    margin: 3px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
  }
  #one {
    background: #f00;
  }
  #two {
    background: #0f0;
  }
  #three {
    background: #00f;
  }
  section.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="buttons">
  <button id="show" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button>
  <button id="hide" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hide Me Now!</button>
</section>
<div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div>
<div id="three">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
  div {
      margin: 3px;
      width: 80px;
      display: none;
      height: 80px;
      float: left;
  }
  #one {
      background: #f00;
  }
  #two {
      background: #0f0;
  }
  #three {
      background: #00f;
  }
  .groupbuttons {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      text-align:center;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit- transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      width: 100%;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="groupbuttons">
    <button id="show" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button>
    <button id="hide" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hide Me Now!</button>
</div>
<div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div>
<div id="three">3</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/um7ctpnj/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

You were setting divs to `display:none;` which is why they were disappearing. Change that CSS to a class, and apply it to the boxes.

Then apply the new CSS code to vertically align, and make sure the height of `html` and `body` are set.

https://jsfiddle.net/um7ctpnj/15/

Note: the vertical align code was found from this tutorial: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why the buttons disappear when placed in a div because I'm not familiar with jQuery, but you can use:

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: A quick look at the CSS would explain exactly they disappear when placed in a div, as the poster has a global CSS rule to `display:none` for all `div`s

Comment: jQuery isn't the issue for the DIVs not displaying. See the OPs `div` CSS selector.

Comment: The question didn't ask for an answer as to why placing a div around the buttons hid them, and neither did I. I'm was not going to change how the divs were displayed in the css, because I didn't want to mess with her functionality not knowing jQuery. I could easily have suggested to her to add a class to the hidden divs and hide that instead of every div and then surround the buttons in a div with the margin of margin:0 auto, but instead I provided the simplest solution I knew, which would centering all the text in the body. You're going to down vote me for providing an answer to the question?

Comment: Someone down voted you because your answer doesn't satisfy the question. Not because you made a suggestion that suggested jQuery might have something to do with the buttons disappearing when placed in a DIV. That suggestion was corrected via comments.